# Rename files created in hadoop - Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The files created in HDFS via write has its own naming convention. To change it to custom name there is an option via script using `hadoop fs -mv oldname newname`

Is there any other option available in Spark/ Hadoop to provide custom name to created file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache Spark does not provide any Api for file system operations in hdfs. But you can always use the Hadoop file system APIs to rename the file in HDFS. [Check](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) this for more details of the Hadoop file system APIs available. For renaming , the following will work :

```
val conf = new Configuration();
val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
fileSystem.mkdir(new Path(newhdfs_dirPath));
fileSystem.rename(new Path(existinghdfs_dirpath+oldname), new Path(newhdfs_dirPath+newname));
```